# How to put a Mongo Db URL in dotenv file?

Tags: mongodb, dotenv

I'm trying to add environment file to a node project, and I have put mongo URL in it, now, when I console log it, prints undefined... anyone know where's the problem?

```
require("dotenv").config();
let MONGO_URL = process.env.MONGO_DB_URL;
console.log("MONGO", process.env.MONGO_DB_URL);
```

dotenv file

```
MONGO_DB_URL="mongo URL"
```

if I print

```
console.log(require('dotenv'.config()))

CONFIG { parsed: { MONGO_DB_URL: '' } }
```

Comment: ...more : if i remove "" and add `url...` (with backticks), it print the url like this : `url .... `

Comment: Immediately after `require("dotenv").config()` what is `console.log(process.env)`?

Comment: Check if your `.env` file is in the root folder of the server (in the same hierarchy as the `app.js` if that's your main file).

Comment: @rickhg12hs just fixed it, the problem was a breakline in vs code after formatter applied. thank u :)

Comment: @NeNaD just fixed it, the problem was a breakline in vs code after formatter applied. thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

check if you had install npm package of dotenv

if yes then it will work else you need to install it

> npm i dotenv

- in .env file

> MONGO_DB_URL= mongodb://localhost:27017

- in index file or wherever u want

```
require("dotenv").config();
let MONGO_URL = process.env.MONGO_DB_URL;
```

Comment: just fixed it, the problem was a breakline in vs code after formatter applied, thank u :)